# Add text to a video file

Tags: c#, video, subtitle

I need to add text to a video file. I need to read one video file and add one line of text to it.

Comment: Should this happen while streaming, or are you saving the videos to file? Are you happy with doing this in a video editor because it's a one-off situation, or do you need something more reusable?

Comment: Please be (much) more specific regarding your scenario - you need captions, right? Do they vary during the video or is it just one static line of text?

Answer (score 2):

You are stepping into a highly neglected area. I mean MS is really ignoring it and even the most simple things turn out into a mess very quickly.

Now for your options:

- check out [DirectShow.net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)
  project. It wrapps DirectShow library
  and let you do all sort of stuff over
  video.
- somebody showed (google
  around) how to play video on WPF. You
  could easily add text or whatever but
  I am not sure about saving.

Comment: Huh, why was this anwer downvoted? +1

Answer (score 1):

Read up on video alpha blending.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a question, you need to be specific and give context otherwise it's hard for people to help.

You say you need to add a line of text, is this a one-off activity; 1 video, 1 line of text? Are you needing to display a line of text while showing video; multiple videos with a line of text each? The list of potential scenarios is virtually endless and you've not indicated what you've tried to achieve this already.

Just tagging it as C# isn't going to help I fear.

Answer (score 0):

Both DirectShow VRM7 and VRM9 (video renderers) allow you to do that when displaying video.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use command line and run extra tool from ?
For exaple, ffmpeg or VideoCHarge Studio